# What are your favorite Powershell Cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I just found /n softwares free Powershell NetCmdlets, and after playing with them I love the functionality they bring to the command line.  So it raises the question what are your favorite Cmdlets, and how do you use them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a programmer/hacker, `Get-Member` and `Get-Command` are the ones I use more than any others, but the ones I use to show off are `Select-Control` and `Send-Keys` from [WASP](http://CodePlex.com/WASP), the [PowerGadgets](http://PowerGadgets.com), and some of my own stuff written in WPF against CTP2 or [PoshConsole](http://CodePlex.com/PoshConsole) ;-)

[image: Weather in PoshConsole]

Comment: Hey jaykul, I noticed you posted a weather forecast for my home town.  Well Rush, NY, is my home town, but West Henrietta is like a second home town.  :)  Nice to meet you.

Answer (score 8):

there's an [out-twitter script](http://blog.sapien.com/index.php/2008/06/23/out-twitter/) i use for posting to twitter. it's nice, as it means you can send something to twitter without the risk of being distracted by a browser.

i added an alias for it, "twit".

so now you can type, for example:

```
PS C:\>"trying out stack overflow" | twit
```

and if successfully lodged, it will return an integer that identifies your post.

Answer (score 4):

Get-Member, hands down. No, it's not very glamorous, but the ability to inspect objects interactively beats interrupting your work to go hit up MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

**Set-Clipboard**, found on the PowerShell Community Extensions project on CodePlex. Usually when I'm working in PowerShell, the ultimate goal is to generate some text or even an Excel spreadsheet. Set-Clipboard eliminates all of the intermediate "save it to a file, ok now open that file, select all, copy to clipboard" steps--you do it all in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a PowerShell provider to give me access to IE7's RSS feed store, and had lots of fun with it.

It lets me `cd` to a drive called `feed:` and navigate around folders and feeds using `cd` and `dir`.
It even lets you add or remove feeds from the command line.

See this post on my blog as an example:

[Getting the Most Prolific Authors in your Feeds](http://www.madprops.org/blog/getting-the-most-prolific-authors-in-your-feeds/)

It's rolled up into the PowerShell Community Extensions project nowadays, which you can find on CodePlex [here](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerShellCX).

Answer (score 2):

While it is not as fun as Out-Twitter, my favorite cmdlet is Get-Member, since it allows me to examine any of the objects I'm working with and find out new properties and methods, as well as the underlying type of the object.

If I did not choose Get-Member, I would have to go with Out-Clipboard from the PowerShell Community Extensions (PSCX), as it enables a whole lot of clipboard automation and makes using PowerShell for code templating much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is a little bland, but I would vote for Get-Help.

Answer (score 1):

**export-csv**. This creates a nice report in a manager-friendly Excel-ready format. Bonus points if you have community extensions installed and user **send-smtpmail**.

Management report in their inbox from the commandline. Nice.

Comment: +1 I was not aware of this, extremely useful!

Answer (score 0):

While semi-related to your question, it does not entirely fit the Powershell NetCmdlets motif. But I wanted to post it anyhow as I use it daily and it may help others. Simply making shift-control-c key combo into displaying the visual studio command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

ls (Get-ChildItem)
rm (Remove-Item)
ps (Get-Process)

and the rest of my familiar commands that now "just work" :)

but seriously... New-Object would have to get my vote.  With it, powershell can do ANYTHING :)

Answer (score 0):

I find Get-member to be the most useful native PowerShell cmdlet. I also use Get-WMIObject on a daily basis.  Even if I'm troubleshooting a VBScript problem for someone I'll turn to Get-WMIObject because I can work with WMI interactively.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of Get-WMIObject and Get-Member is something I use throughout the workday.  Working on Get-Sandwich.

Answer (score 0):

I do alot of work with Microsoft Lync 2010 which includes a set of synthetic for testing functionality. Of these Test-CsPstnOutboundCall is my favourite.

For general scripting got to vote for get-member and get-help :)